# Can I force a program to run with a .NET Framework 4.x version that is different from the one that comes with Windows 11?

Tags: .net, windows, compatibility

In our company, we are using a specific version of a commercial software. This software is written in C# and targets the .NET Framework v4.6.1. It has been working just fine until recently on multiple Windows 10 and 11 computers.

Recently, the software has stopped working on any PC that is running Windows 11. After a bit of back and forth with the vendor of the software it has become clear that the software is not compatible with .NET Framework v4.8.1. It works fine with any .NET Framework until v4.8. Apparently it has something to do with the obfuscation tool they use.
The problem seems to be that starting from Windows 11 22H2, .NET Framework v4.8.1 is integrated into Windows and it is not possible to uninstall it or install any prior version.

Obviously there are multiple routes we could try to solve this problem (unfortunately the vendor of the software is not very helpful). In this question I want to focus on one particular route, as fits the topic of this stack exchange:

Can I somehow force this software to use a .NET Framework version that is different from the one that comes preinstalled with Windows 11 22H2? Obviously I don't have access to the source code, I just have the compiled binaries. However, the `XXX.exe.config` file seems to be a possible candidate for tinkering. For example there is this block:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
```

I tried tinkering with the `version` parameter by setting a specific build version. This gave me this error message:

[image: error message]

When I click on 'Yes' this sends me to this page: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net481?cid=getdotnetframework

Here I can indeed download older .NET Framework *runtimes*, however I cannot install them. The installer says (correctly) that a newer version of .NET Framework is already installed.

I can download and install the *developer* packs for older .NET Framework versions, however I did not manage to use these to run the software. Is there a way to do this? Do the assembly redirect entries in the `XXX.exe.config` have anything to do with this?

To sum it up, I would like to know:
Can I somehow run this software on Windows 11 22H2 using a .NET Framework version between v4.6.1 and 4.8, despite the fact that Windows 11 22H2 comes with .NET Framework v4.8.1 preinstalled?

Comment: You can't, you can only specify the *minimum* version.  They'll have to remove obfuscation until the vendor fixes this bug.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that's what I feared. Unfortunately it seems unlikely that the vendor of the software will do anything to help us here, I suspect they would rather have us buy the newest version of their product...

Comment: Hopefully its in a competitive market where alternative vendors might be considered. MS have put a lot of effort into backwards compatibility for both .NET and Windows. Their obfuscation tool is in fact now harming a legitimate customer and preventing a normal upgrade path.

Comment: Unfortunately this is also not the case. The software is needed to run some (expensive) hardware from the same vendor. Competitors do exist, but not quite on the same performance level. I guess that is why they can get away with this.